# Add serialization and deserialization support for custom type in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, serialization

Lets say we have a custom type:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Foo("{self.value}")'
```

How to use/extend [`json.JSONEncoder`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder) and [`json.JSONDecoder`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONDecoder) so that instances of `Foo` would be serialized and deserialized? Expectation:

```
>>> foo = Foo('bar')
>>> foo
... Foo("bar")
>>> FooJSONEncoder().encode([foo])
... '[Foo("bar")]'
>>> FooJSONDecoder().decode('[Foo("bar")]')
... [Foo("bar")]
```

I have tried overriding [`json.JSONEncoder.default(o)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder.default):

```
class FooJSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, Foo):
            return f'Foo("{o.value}")'
        return super().default(o)
```

But custom type gets converted to string and it gets deserialized as a string.

```
>>> FooJSONEncoder().encode([foo])
... '["Foo(\\"bar\\")"]'
>>> json.JSONDecoder().decode('["Foo(\\"bar\\")"]')
... ['Foo("bar")']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A custom type should be serialized to a dictionary (not a string and not a `Foo` type as provided in the expectations):

```
class FooJSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, Foo):
            return {'__type__': o.__class__.__name__, 'value': o.value}
        return super().default(o)
```

Now `foo` instance serializes to:

```
>>> FooJSONEncoder().encode(foo)
... '{"__type__": "Foo", "value": "bar"}'
```

In order to decerialize it, a custom [`json.JSONDecoder.object_hook`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONDecoder) has to be implemented:

```
def foo_hook(dct):
    if dct.get('__type__') == 'Foo':
        return Foo(value=dct.get('value'))
    return dct
```

And provided for the `JSONDecoder`, e.g.:

```
>>> serialized_foo = FooJSONEncoder().encode(foo)
>>> json.JSONDecoder(object_hook=foo_hook).decode(serialized_foo)
... Foo("bar")
>>> json.loads(serialized_foo, object_hook=foo_hook)
... Foo("bar")
```